# How to create drop-list to hold the sub-menu items

Tags: html, css

The page contains a side menu bar and the menu bar contains 5-6 Contents.
And the contents contains sub-Contents
How can wrap the sub-content into the main content and make the sub-content invisible until someone clicks on the main content.
is it possible to do so ? I've many sub-contents but for demo purpose i have shown only 5-6 mqain content and 3-4 sub content under one main content.

```js
function openNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
}

function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
}
```

```css
<style>
body {
    font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
}

.sidenav {
    height: 100%;
    width: 0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #111;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    transition: 0.5s;
    padding-top: 60px;
}

.sidenav a {
    padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #818181;
    display: block;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.sidenav a:hover {
    color: #f1f1f1;
}

.sidenav .closebtn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 25px;
    font-size: 36px;
    margin-left: 50px;
}

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .sidenav {padding-top: 15px;}
  .sidenav a {font-size: 18px;}
}
</style>
```

```html
<body>

<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
  <div class="user" style="background-image:url(ava.jpg)"></div>
    
    <ul class="nano-content">
            
    <li class="sub-menu">
        <a href="javascript:void(0);"><i class="fa fa-cogs"></i><span>Popular Links</span><i class="arrow fa fa-angle-right pull-right"></i></a>
        <ul>

          <li><a href="ui-alerts-notifications.html">Java Database Connectivity Code</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="ui-panels.html">Java Mail Api</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="ui-buttons.html">java Itext</a>
          
    </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
    
  <a href="#">About</a>
  <a href="#">Services</a>
  <a href="#">Clients</a>
  <a href="#">Contact</a>
</div>

<span style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()">&#9776;</span>


</body>
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
function openNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
}

function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
}
  
var hasSubMenu = document.querySelectorAll('.hasSubMenu');

hasSubMenu.forEach(function(i,q){
  i.addEventListener('click',function(){
    this.classList.toggle('clicked');
  })
})
```

```css
body {
    font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
}

.sidenav {
    height: 100%;
    width: 0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #111;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    transition: 0.5s;
    padding-top: 60px;
}

.sidenav a {
    padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #818181;
    display: block;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.sidenav a:hover {
    color: #f1f1f1;
}

.sidenav .closebtn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 25px;
    font-size: 36px;
    margin-left: 50px;
}

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .sidenav {padding-top: 15px;}
  .sidenav a {font-size: 18px;}
}

.hasSubMenu + ul{
  display: none;
}
.clicked + ul{
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
  <div class="user" style="background-image:url(ava.jpg)"></div>
    
    <ul class="nano-content">
            
    <li class="sub-menu">
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="hasSubMenu" ><i class="fa fa-cogs"></i><span>Popular Links</span><i class="arrow fa fa-angle-right pull-right"></i></a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="ui-alerts-notifications.html">Java Database Connectivity Code</a></li>
          <li><a href="ui-panels.html">Java Mail Api</a></li>
          <li><a href="ui-buttons.html">java Itext</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    </ul>
    
  <a href="#">About</a>
  <a href="#">Services</a>
  <a href="#">Clients</a>
  <a href="#">Contact</a>
</div>

<span style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()">&#9776;</span>
```

It's just **SAMPLE CODE**.

You should try to learn how to make better code.